# CHECK CONSTRAINT in SQL SERVER Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, check-constraints

Here is my use case, simplified.

Two tables **MyHeaderTable**, **MyLinesTable**;

```
MyHeaderTable
-------------
pkID [int]
fname
lname
LineID [varchar(8)]
blah1


MyLinesTable
-------------
pkLinID [varchar(8)]
start_date
end_date
blah2
```

I want to restrict the primary-key for **MyLinesTable.pkLinID** to come from a column in another table **MyHeaderTable.LineID**

What is the syntax to set pkLinID = [only values from] MyHeadersTable.LineID

**What I tried so far**

Select MyLinesTable / right-click `Design` / right-click `Check Constraint...` / Add / Expression.

Then I am stuck, what is the syntax for Expression?

If I use the expression
pkLinID = '12345678'
the user interface happily takes it, but obviously i want a set of values from the other table.

P.S. I've done this hundreds of tines with PrimaryKey and ForeignKey constraints, where I just drag and drop, but this is totally different.

**EDIT: Example to clarify:**
MyHeadersTable has 100 rows, with say values 1 to 100 in MyHeaders.LineID but
myLinestable only has 2 rows, with values myLinestable.pkLinID = 50 and 99; whenever someone inserts a record in MyLinesTable, I want to restrict it to those  already existing in MyHeadersTable, and let the DB enforce validation (with contraints, or whatever mechanism is available).

Comment: What you're describing here appears to still be a Foreign Key.

Comment: Foreign keys don't only reference primary keys - they can also reference unique key constraints, which a table can have multiple of.

Comment: *"but obviously i want a set of values from the other table"* What do you mean by a "set of values", this is no obvious. A single row and column contains a **single** value, not a "set".

Comment: @Lamu "set of values" MyHeaderTable.LineID row 1 put .LineID = 123, for row 2 put LineID=456, for row3 put LineID=123. here you are i have two distinct "set of values" in just the first 3 rows.

Comment: So why is this *not* a foreign key? Also, you should really be using T-SQL to create your constraints, not relying to the (flakey at best) GUI in SSMS.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever but my field MyHeaderTable.LineID is not a unique constraint, because i intend to repeat it ad nauseum across rows.

Comment: No, it should be a unique/primary key in `MyLinesTable`, @joedotnot. It's a foreign key in `MyHeaderTable`

Comment: Then you can't do what you want with a constraint, directly. `CHECK` constraints are meant to check either a single column itself or *at most* multiple columns of a single row of a table. There are some fudges using user-defined functions but those are often a mistake.

Comment: @Lamu. no it should not, that is not my use case; ,I can have 100 Rows in MyHeaders table, with say values 1 to 100 in MyHeaders.LineID but only 2 rows in myLinestable.pkLinID = 50 and 99; so whenever someone inserts a record in MyLinesTable i want to restrict it to those from MyHeadersTable, and let the DB enforce validation.

Comment: You could enforce this business rule using a trigger--if an inserted/updated value is not in the referenced table, raise an error and the trigger will roll back the transaction. Triggers  however, are best considered as Evil and to be avoided at all costs whenever possible.

Comment: Also: what happens when a row is validly added to MyLinesTable, and then the "validating" data in MyHeaderTable is removed?

Comment: @PhilipKelley I've avoided triggers for 20+ years cause they are annoying (or evil), so that aspect is covered. What should happen when the "validating" data is removed is the DB should prevent it from being removed - Like it does in the normal scenario of Parent / Child tables. Anyway, thanks for commenting, I give up - I figured my scenario is not supported in a straight-forward way out of the box (so help me, Codd !)